# How can I sum value of duplicate row and show in gridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, gridview

I Have some record in my database I would like to check the cell value are or not in Column P_ID and Size.  If the value are same then sum of Column Quantity and show only one record in gridview and result of sum of quantity  but if not just show all column

My database look like these
ID - Size   -  Quantity
14  - 90    -    2
14 -  90     -   1
14  - 80       - 1
14  - 90      -  3

and the result that i expect to show in Gridview is
ID -      Size -     Quantity
14  -      90     -   6
14   -    80     -   1

I try this in many days but i can't please help me.
PS.I'm a newbie programmer I use LinQ to dev but I Think i can adapt from VB.C# to LInQ Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
var result = from t in db.tableName
             group x by new { x.ID, x.Size } into gr
             select new
             {
                 ID = gr.Key.ID,
                 Size = gr.Key.Size
                 Quantity = gr.Sum(q=>q.Quantity)
             };
```

where `db.tableName` refers to your table in db.

What we do above is a group by of our records in two columns. Then we select that we want.

Comment: Thank you very much. I never know GROUP BY  before you told me. Your code is not work because there are some error about lamda expression or something but Your idea made me hopeful ;)

Comment: woodenDataContext db = new woodenDataContext();

var result = (from i in db.PurchaseOrderLists
group i by new { i.product.Door_Number,i.PODL_Size } into g
select new { doorNumber = g.Key.Door_Number,Size = g.Key.PODL_Size, Quantity = g.Sum(s => s.PODL_Quantity) });

This is my code  thank you

Comment: @JojiJo great ! Unfortunately, I didn't know the exact names of your columns.